# 5.1 surround sound settings?

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm trying to configure my 5.1 on Ubuntu, but I'm not managing to.
I've followed all tutorials and explanations shown on askubuntu and arounds, changing the daemon.conf file to 6 and all, but:

- Running speaker-test -c6 -twav now does act as if a 5.1 system was in place, but sound only comes as on a 2.0 (no bass, only two front speakers).
- Youtube Video to test speakers do not reach to make surround experience at all (rear left, rear right, and center do not sound). Surprisingly enough, the lfe does.
- On Sound settings, I was expecting I would be able to see the new configuration, something along the lines of the Realtek Sound driver where you have all 6 elements there... but I could only see this:
  [image: List item]
- I am unable to understand what does alsamixer showw when I open it. Yes, a lot of bars there, but I don't grasp how to use it. On this matter, launching `alsamixer` I always get Nvidia GPU HDMI as default, needing to select the proper sound card (F6). When managing to select the correct card, as I said, I only see this:

[image]

Could anyone please throw some insight as on what to do to get my audio working? (ideally with the proper show display on the Settings area?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but having the same issue I had to manually modify the `.conf` file of Alsamixer to enable 6 speakers.

In a terminal run:

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Replace the number of channels from `2` to `6` at the line:

```
default-sample-channels = 6
```

and add the missing speakers in the next line:

```
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then log out and log back in to your session.

You'll finally be able to see all your speakers in the Settings → *Sound* menu.